# VS 2015 (community) C# Shared Project IntelliSense summaries only showing "to be added"

Tags: c#, .net, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I have tried to set up a project in Visual Studio 2015 to develop a mobile app for multiple platforms (Android, iOS, WinPhone) by following this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx

In the solution I have two projects for the two platforms (Android and WinPhone) and a "Shared Project" to share the code between the two. But for some reason the method summaries displayed in IntelliSense only shows "To be added". This is however only for methods within the System namespace and not from e.g. Newtonsoft.Json.

**Example**:
When hovering the mouse cursor over the Create method in the following line shows "To be added"

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);
```

, but in the below line it shows "Deserializes the JSON to a .NET object."

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
```

Is there a way get some actual descriptions of the methods?

Comment: This is apparently coming from Xamarin, they have many of these.

Comment: @GSerg Oh, so there's no way to get around it? We just have to wait for them to fix it?